# bitbucket pipeline to heroku auth fail

Tags: heroku, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying to get my BitBucket Pipeline to deploy to Heroku using the method described here:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/deploy-to-heroku-872013667.html

but it fails with the error:

```
remote: !   WARNING:
remote: !   Do not authenticate with username and password using git.
remote: !   Run `heroku login` to update your credentials, then retry 
the git command.
```

Can I login through a Heroku Pipeline as it describes or is there another solution?

Comment: That looks like a warning, not an error. What do you see after that?

Comment: fatal: Authentication failed

Comment: and the build process fails

Comment: Okay, _that_ looks like an error :-). Just to be sure, you are using your API key, not your password, right?

Comment: yes using the API key from Heroku, passing as HEROKU_API_KEY from Bitbucket Environment variables

Comment: I've also tried hard coding the api key into the pipeline script to see if that works but the same error

Comment: According to Heroku's documentation that message is shown for [any authentication error](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git). Have a look in your `~/.netrc` file and make sure the token you're trying to use exactly matches what's in there.

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to include actual token in the `HEROKU_API_KEY` env var:

```
$ heroku authorizations
Heroku CLI login from emily  d7cefd7d-6570-40cd-b510-84158323c238  global
# this is _not_ what you need

$ heroku authorizations:info d7cefd7d-6570-40cd-b510-84158323c238
...
Token: f1a255ee-c92c-49ee-8935-c430a7ad6a53 <-- this is what you need
...
```

An alternative:

```
$ heroku authorizations --json
...
    "access_token": {
      "expires_in": null,
      "id": "a890965c-bebd-43c7-af17-41225e92d0df",
      "token": "f1a255ee-c92c-49ee-8935-c430a7ad6a53" // <-- this is what you need
    },
...
```